# Using one legged OAuth1 in C#, gets error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, rest, oauth, unauthorized

I am using an one legged OAuth1 web service! which means I don't need to get a token to get my result just consumer key and secret is enough.I have used many different APIs and got the same result every time,I don't get what I'm doing wrong!
here is the latest API I've used:
https://github.com/rhargreaves/oauth-dotnetcore

the OAuth classes are pretty much straight forward,I've used those and made my request this way:

```
 OAuthRequest client = OAuthRequest.ForRequestToken("key", "secret");
        client.RequestUrl = "http://some site/?q=api/sbu_rest/user_books_returned/username";
        // For HTTP header authorization
        string auth = client.GetAuthorizationHeader();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(client.RequestUrl);

        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

but I get the error:

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

It's worth to mention that I have checked my URL ,key and secret in postman and they work fine(I'll get the result I want which is a list of books!)

PS: the signature method is HMAC-SHA1